# SQL Server 2008 R2 service pack steps .....on cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustering

I have a sp3 to apply on SQL Server 2008 R2 on windows 2008 R2 cluster with four nodes and 6 instances. Node 4 do not have any resources but is possible owner for all the instances.

Steps I am planing

1. remove node 4 as possible owner for all SQL related resources
2. reboot node 4, apply sp3, reboot node 4
3. put back node 4 as possible owner for all node 1 SQL resources
4. failover node 1 resources to node 4
5. repeat step 2 for node 1
6. repeat step 3 for node 1
7. failover node 4 resources back to node 1
8. put back node 4as possible owner for all node 2 SQL resources
9. repeat step 4 for node 2
10. repeat steps 5,6,7 for node 2
11. repeat steps 4,5,6,7 for node

Please verify and confirm or correct my steps.

I guess sp3 + cumulative update for 6 instances per node around 1.5 hrs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would make a slight modification to the procedure to reduce the number of failovers:

1. Remove Nodes 3 and 4 from the list of possible owners for each SQL Server Cluster Instance, leaving Nodes 1 and 2 as possible owners to preserve failover capability while doing the rolling upgrade.
2. Apply the Service Pack and latest Cumulative Update to nodes 3 and 4.  Reboot as necessary.
3. Make nodes 3 and 4 possible owners for all clustered instances.
4. Failover the clustered instances to either node 3 or 4.
5. Remove nodes 1 and 2 from the list of possible owners.
6. Apply the Service Pack and latest Cumulative Update to nodes 1 and 2.  Reboot as necessary.
7. Add nodes 1 and 2 back in as possible owners.
8. Leave the instances on node 3 or 4, or fail them back to node 1, if desired.

Microsoft has [documentation providing more details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/958734) if required.